# Prevent unused text boxes "Click To Enter Text" from printing on completed form

Tags: microsoft-word

I  built a form in Word. There are several text boxes, all of which display "Click To Enter Text" before the user adds some content.  Once they fill out the document and print it, it displays all unused "Click To Enter Text".  Is there a way to exclude the unused text boxes?